# Direct Celery task logs to a single file

Tags: django, celery

I'm trying to use the logging config in settings.py to redirect Celery task logs into a file.

Here is my task:

```
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    logger.info('Adding %s + %s' % (x, y))
    return x + y
```

And here is my logging config:

```
'handlers': {
        'myappLog': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': "myapp.log",
            'maxBytes': 5242880,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'myapp.myapp.tasks.add': {
            'handlers': ['myappLog'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
```

Currently, I see the log in the console, but not to the log file. The log file gets created, but it's empty.

Answer (score 4):

In the loggers you define logger that is never created (`myapp.myapp.tasks.add`). You give the module name to `getLogger` which is probably `myapp.myapp.tasks`. Try this:

```
...
'loggers': {
  'myapp.myapp.tasks': {
...
```

When you use `get_task_logger` all the loggers have parent named `celery.task` so you can do this to apply handler to all celery tasks:

```
...   
'loggers': {
  'celery.task': {
...
```

Comment: Bingo. Just to clarify, you create your logger with `__name__` as the argument which resolves to the module, not the function name you're wrapping as a task.